# Openness behavior in Banach spaces.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-optimization

Let $A$ be a closed, bounded, and convex subset of the Banach space $X.$ Suppose $V$ is a convex and open subset of $X$ containing $A,$  $( A \subset V).$ Is there an open neighborhood of zero, say $U$ in $X$ such that $A+U \subseteq V$ ?

I know that When $A$ is weakly compact, the answer is yes, but general case is unclear to me!

Comment: You probably want $U\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Could you not take $X = \ell^\infty$, $A = \{(a_j)_{j=1}^\infty : |a_j| \leq 1\}$, $V = \{(a_j)_{j=1}^\infty : |a_j| < 1 + {1 \over j}\}$?

Comment: No!  $a=(1,1,1,1,...) \in V$, but $a$ is not a interior point of $V.$ so $V$ is not open in your examples

Answer (score 0):

If X is reflexive then the answer is yes (based on your argument in the case of weakly compact A). In fact, if X is reflexive then the closed unit ball of X is weakly compact. Since, A is bounded, it is contained in rBall(X) for some r>0. A is also weakly closed since it is norm closed and convex. Thus A is weakly compact. Now use your result on weakly compact case.